# Is there a built-in interface for flex properties such as align-items and justify-content?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am writing an interface with `flexAlignItems` and `flexJustifyContent` properties and instead of adding the values by hand, I am looking for something similar to `HTMLAnchorElement`.

```
interface ContainerProps {
  flexAlignItems?: "center" | "flex-start" | "flex-end" | "stretch"
  flexJustifyContent?:
    | "center"
    | "flex-start"
    | "flex-end"
    | "space-around"
    | "space-between"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind not prefixing the properties with `flex-`:

```
interface ContainerProps extends Pick<React.CSSProperties, 'alignItems' | 'justifyContent' /* add others */> {

}
```

And you'll end up with `ContainerProps` having properties such as `alignItems` etc.

If you want the prefix there you'll need to do a bit of typing:

```
interface ContainerProps {
  flexAlignItems?: React.CSSProperties['alignItems'];
  // add others
}
```

Comment: That’s amazing! Do you know how to remove the type `string` from `React.CSSProperties['alignItems']`? Not sure why it’s part of the `align-items` default type definitions.

Answer (score 1):

[CSSStyleDeclaration](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/src/lib/dom.generated.d.ts) interface for [HTMLElement.style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ElementCSSInlineStyle/style) doesn't have constrained types for properties

**But!**

Since we are in React world there is [React.CSSProperties](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/e434515761b36830c3e58a970abf5186f005adac/types/react/index.d.ts) interface ready to use.

```js
interface ContainerProps extends React.CSSProperties {
}
```